# How to fix fatal error encountered during command execution in asp.net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I am getting error in `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery`. When I add data in the web form it says:

> 'an exception of type MySql.Data,MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll but was not found in user code. Additional Info..fatal error encountered during command execution.

I can't find why it is resulting in a fatal error.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=fir;Integrated Security=True;User Name=root;Password=;";
    con.Open();
}

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into reportcrime" + "(Name,CNIC,Phone1,Phone2,Email,Gender,City,Address,CrimeType,CrimeDetail)values(@Name,@CNIC NO,@ContactNo.1,@ContactNo.2,@Email Address,@Gender,@City Name,@Postal Address,@Crime Type,@Crime Detail)",con);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name",txtName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CNIC NO",txtCnicNo.Text.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact No.1",txtcontactNo1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact No.2",txtcontactNo2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email Address",txtEmail.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender",ddlGender.SelectedItem.Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City Name",txtCityName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Postal Address",txtaddress.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Crime Type",ddlCrimeType.SelectedItem.Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Crime Details",txtCrimeDetails.Text);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Your query doesn't look normal means too much typo! but could you please add inner exception from exception you got?

Comment: InnerException: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
       HResult=-2147467259
       Message=Parameter '@CNIC' must be defined.
       Source=MySql.Data
       ErrorCode=-2147467259
       Number=0

Comment: First of all, replace the space in parameter name with underscore that means from `@CNIC NO` to `@CNIC_NO` and same for all

Comment: And your query must differentiate the keywords and variables by proper spacing like `INSERT INTO Tablename (C1, C2, C3) VALUES (@P1, @P2, @P3)` so kindly mention the spaces in my query and compare it with yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fatal error here is due to an exception was caused by your code due to a mistake that you made. As you have stated its in your sql query you can know this because your exception is of type MySqlException.

Now you should inspect the exception most Inner Exception and read its message. It will go something like this 'Error while parsing query' most likely its complaining because you cannot have spaces in you parameter names.

Comment: in inner exception , it says " Message=Parameter '@CNIC' must be defined" . what is meant?

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked the column name, whether it is "CNIC NO"?